# Not able to execute a task in Background using apscheduler

Tags: python-2.7, apscheduler

I used Blockingscheduler before, but I am facing problem using Backgroundscheduler.

Need to run a scheduler task after returning a value, but the scheduled task is never executed.

```
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def my_job(text):
    print(text)
def job1():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    sched = BackgroundScheduler()
    sched.add_job(my_job, 'date', run_date=now + 
datetime.timedelta(seconds = 20), args=['text'])
    sched.start()

def fun1():
    try:
        return "hello"
    finally:
        job1()
print fun1()
```

I am getting only output as "hello" and the code is exiting. Expected output is "hello" and "text" which should be executed once after 20seconds. Please let me know what I messed up!!

Comment: Why are you no longer using BlockingScheduler? You need it to prevent the script from exiting at the end since your program isn't doing anything else.

Comment: I tried Blocking scheduler also, but no luck. My original requirement is to run a SQL query exactly after 10mins after a function is executed. As per the documentation of APSCHEDULER. Backgroundscheduler is recommended for my purpose.

BlockingScheduler: use when the scheduler is the only thing running in your process
BackgroundScheduler: use when you’re not using any of the frameworks below, and want the scheduler to run in the background inside your application

Comment: It seems that the snippet above is not representative of how your application works because it is getting these queries from somewhere, and that something has to be running in the main thread, right? In that case the background scheduler is the right thing to use. But are you saying that your script is still exiting even in that case?

Comment: Anyhow, I've told you why the snippet you provided doesn't work. I can give you better advice if you replace it with something more representative of the actual application.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this FAQ entry](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html) enlightening.

To summarize, a Python script will exit once it reaches to the end, unless non-daemonic threads are active. The scheduler thread is daemonic by default.

Furthermore, it is bad practice to create a new scheduler in a function and not save the instance in a global variable which could be used to schedule further jobs or to shut down the scheduler. The way your code works now is that it will keep creating new schedulers without shutting down the previous ones.